# C++ WxWidgets: Single log window for messages from Multiple Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets, logging

What's the best/proper method to collect log messages from multiple threads and have them all be displayed using a window? (while the threads are running).

I am currently trying to redirect stdout (cout) in to a wxTextCtrl but failing miserably when attempting to do so over multiple threads. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging has had a few major updates recently in the wxWidgets trunk, you can read about them [here](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2009/07/blogging-about-logging.html). One of them is to add support for logging from threads other than the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

In what way is it failing? I'm not familiar with the wxTextCtrl, but unless it has built in synchronization (ie. its thread safe) that could be a big issue. The simplest way to protect a single resource like this is via a named 'mutex'. The following example is what you can do in each thread to make sure that only one accesses this resource (the output window) at a time.

```
// In each thread's initialization:
HANDLE mutexHandle = CreateMutex(0,FALSE,"__my_protecting_mutex__");


// Whenever you use the debug output:

WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, /* Timeout if you like. */ 0xFFFFFFFF );
// Do our printing here.
ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);


// In each thread's cleanup:
CloseHandle(mutexHandle);
```

So this basically guarantees that only one thread can be in between the wait and the release. Now if your issue is actually routing to the wxTextCtrl, I would need some more details.

**Edit:** I just realized that what I posted is Windows specific, and maybe you aren't on windows! If you aren't I don't have experience with other platform's synchronization methods, but boost has some generic libraries which are not platform specific.

Comment: wxWidgets has a built in, cross-platform wxMutex class
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxmutex.html

Comment: Synchronization is only part of it. It's a bad idea to write directly to a wxTextCtrl from different threads, a much better way is to add log messages to a thread-safe (synchronized) data structure, and have the main GUI thread do the logging to the text control from the queued data. wxWidgets trunk has this now, see the other answer.